# Increment/Decrement value from NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, decimal, numeric, numericupdown

I have the following problem. I create a form with two NumericUpDown and I want to increment/decrement the value from them by 0.01. I tried to use NumericUpDownObject.Increment=0.01M, but there is no change after that, the value don't change. This is the code:

```
namespace Proiect1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int i = 1;
        int o = 1;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            Label l2 = new Label();
            NumericUpDown t = new NumericUpDown();
            NumericUpDown t2 = new NumericUpDown();
            l.Top = i * 25;
            l.Left = 3;
            l2.Top = i * 25;
            l2.Left = 63;
            t.Value = 0;
            t.Increment = 0.01M;
            t.Top = i * 25;
            t.Left = 30;
            t2.Value = 0;
            t2.Top = i * 25;
            t2.Left = 90;
            i++;
            t.Size =new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            t2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            l.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 20);
            l2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(29, 20);
            l.Text = "n" + o;
            l2.Text = "w" + o;
            o++;
            panel1.Controls.Add(t);
            panel1.Controls.Add(t2);
            panel1.Controls.Add(l);
            panel1.Controls.Add(l2);
            panel1.AutoScroll = true;


            
        }
```

Comment: Could it be because you're creating a new `NumericUpDown` on each click?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

This will setup the whole form when it's created, but only increment when clicked.

It looks like your solution is re-creating everything each time it's clicked.

P.s apols - been a while since I did Winforms/WPF

```
namespace Proiect1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        NumericUpDown _t = new NumericUpDown();
        NumericUpDown _t2 = new NumericUpDown();
        Label _l = new Label();
        Label _l2 = new Label();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int i = 1;
            int o = 1;

            
            _l.Top = i * 25;
            _l.Left = 3;
            _l2.Top = i * 25;
            _l2.Left = 63;
            _t.Value = 0;
            _t.Increment = 0.01;
            _t.Top = i * 25;
            _t.Left = 30;
            _t2.Value = 0;
            _t2.Top = i * 25;
            _t2.Left = 90;
            i++;
            _t.Size =new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            _t2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            _l.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 20);
            _l2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(29, 20);
            _l.Text = "n" + o;
            _l2.Text = "w" + o;
            o++;
            panel1.Controls.Add(_t);
            panel1.Controls.Add(_t2);
            panel1.Controls.Add(l_);
            panel1.Controls.Add(l_2);
            panel1.AutoScroll = true;
        }

        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _t.Increment = 0.01;
        }
```

Comment: Increment is just a step. The actual value is Value. So try `t.Value += t.Increment;`

Comment: Now I get the error "The name 't' does not exist in the current context" in public void button1_Click.

Comment: t.Value += t.Increment; don't work either

Comment: If I keep my code as I first post I get this error on t.Increment=0.01M; if I change that to float or whatever "Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'decimal. "

Comment: Can you edit your post to say that? It would have been helpful to know ALL the details

Comment: I've edited my code above (Because it was just wrong), try it again now :)